# wget with Chef when password required to access the URL

Tags: chef-infra, wget

How do I code this with Chef?

```
wget --user=ME --password=PASS projects.example.com/my_folder/myfile.tar.gz
```

Looking at the doc, it would look like this if no password required:

```
remote_file "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/my_file.tar.gz" do
  source "http://projects.example.com/my_folder/my_file.tar.gz"
end
```

now it doesn't look like there is any attributes to pass `user` and `password`

how do I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that this feature was implemented with the fix of [#CHEF-3786](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-3786). 
The username and password are part of the URL:

```
https://user:pass@projects.example.com/my_folder/my_file.tar.gz
```

Comment: Yeah but that still didn't work, I am getting this message now: `Chef::Exceptions::InvalidRemoteFileURI`

`https://me@pass:projects.example.com/folder/file.tar.gz` is not a valid `source` parameter for remote_file. `source` must be an absolute URI or an array of URIs.

Comment: Damn, I knew there was something wrong. I messed up the syntax of the URL. Fixed my answer.